# CakePHP and SOA

Tags: cakephp, soa

I am a PHP developer and wanted to develop a large scale web application in PHP. I have an essay about EMR systems (electronic medical records) using [Service Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) (SOA). I was thinking about using the CakePHP framework.

Is CakePHP good for large scale web applications and is it good for SOA?

I am looking forward to your guidance.

---

thanks for your reply burzum, i am thinking to implement it using REST and CakePHP 2. I found some tutorials on the net and of course at cakephp docs, but i have difficulties to catch the point..using REST with CakePHP.Maybe i need more reading about RESTful WS..any suggestions or links to extra resources will be welcomed

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have a huge app in the same field with over 250 tables and it's working fine and fast. we use a lot of caching techniques and use PostgreSql.

I suggest you to follow the conventions of the framework and get some experience with the Framework before you start building such a huge app that requires high security standards and a good performance.

When it comes to this performance bullshit talk I would say it does not matter which framework you use but how good your team of programmers can use the power of the framework. You can be successfully or build a huge pile of fail with any framework. I've seen both cases in CakePP.

We have played recently a little bullshit bingo with benchmarks for fun and in fact CakePHP 2.1 was beating Yii in their own silly benchmark (just echoing something) if we used more than one simultaneous request. Using a single request Yii was faster.